# Does proguard remove the java assert functions?

Tags: android, release, proguard, assert

I want to use "assert  " assertion in my android project. I want to know   if I create a release build all assert calls are removed.

I searched if Proguard optimization does remove all assertions but couldn't find any information about this.

Does anyone know if Proguard remove "assert" automatically ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assertions are toggled based on a runtime setting, so ProGuard can't generally remove them without changing the behavior of the code.

ProGuard's optimization step only removes an assertion if it can prove that the assertion always holds (and doesn't have any side-effects). This probably only happens for simple assertions. You can check it by disassembling the code with `javap -c`, looking for code that throws `java.lang.AssertionError`.

Note that optimization is disabled with the default configuration file in the Android SDK. To enable it, you have to adapt `project.properties` to point to `proguard-android-optimize.txt` instead of `proguard-android.txt`.